# PHP Script not generating KML file from MySQL data properly - how to correctly approach this?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, geolocation, kml

I have a PHP script which is supposed to output all locations from MySQL to a file called allUsers.kml. 
The document is empty when created though, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document/>
</kml>
```

The KML should contain a user, a location and a list of sports like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<Placemark>
    <name>Anthony</name>
    <userid>1899136</userid>
    <sports>Running</sports>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-2.799667,54.04569</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

but it doesn't.

How can i fix my php to correctly output this document?

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    $con=mysql_connect(PARAMS);

    mysql_select_db("db");
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $lon = $_POST['lon'];

    $sql = "UPDATE userActivityLocation SET lat='$lat', lon='$lon' WHERE user='$user'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    echo $result;
    if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo "Added";
    }   mysql_close($con);

    $sql2="SELECT * FROM userActivityLocation";
    $result2=mysql_query($sql2);

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    // Iterate through the rows, adding KML nodes for each
    // Creates the root KML element and appends it to the root document.
    $node = $dom->createElementNS('http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2', 'kml');
    $parNode = $dom->appendChild($node);

    // Creates a KML Document element and append it to the KML element.
    $dnode = $dom->createElement('Document');
    $docNode = $parNode->appendChild($dnode);


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $dnode = $dom->createElement("Placemark");
        $newnode = $docNode->appendChild($dnode);

        $newnode = $dom->createElement("user");
        $newnode->nodeValue = $row['user'];
        $dnode->appendChild($newnode);

        $newnode = $dom->createElement("sports");  
        $newnode->nodeValue = $row['sports'];
        $dnode->appendChild($newnode);

        //Coordinates are a child node of the 'Point' node       
        $pointnode = $dom->createElement("Point");
        $dnode->appendChild($pointnode);

        $coordsnode = $dom->createElement("coordinates");
        $coordsnode->nodeValue = $row['lon'].",".$row['lat'];
        $pointnode->appendChild($coordsnode);
    }

    $filename = "allUsers.kml";
    $dom->save($filename);
    $msg = "PHP Working - Location - KML Generated";
    echo $msg;
    echo "#####";
    echo $filename;
?>
```

I really would massively appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are closing the SQL connection after 'Add' and hence getting no result for your select query.

```
  } else {
    echo "Added";    
  }   mysql_close($con);  

  $sql2="SELECT * FROM userActivityLocation";  
  $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
```

Move `mysql_close($con);` down to the very bottom of your file and you should be good.